# Exit from Android Application

Tags: android

My application contains 12 activities.Can i exit from the entire application in one click? finish() finishes only a single activity and the previous activity launched. Please help me for fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

When starting the activity from which you want to close all activity, add a flag to the intent.

```
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

this will make your current activity as the top and thus when you will finish this your task will be accomplished

Answer (score 0):

Create static instance of all activities

```
public class Activity1 extends FragmentActivity {

    private static Activity1 sActivity;

    public static Activity1 getsActivity() {
        return sActivity;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sActivity = this;

}

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        sActivity = null
    }
}
}
```

Now create an exit method in your Utility class like and start killing the activity from the higher order, and call it from anywhere inside your app

```
public static void exitApp(){
    if(Acitivity10.getsActivity() != null){
    Activity10.getsActivity.finish();   
}
    if(Acitivity9.getsActivity() != null){
    Activity9.getsActivity.finish();    
}
-
-
if(Acitvity1.getsActivity()!= null){
    Activty1.getsActivity().finish();
}
}
```

Comment: Imagine searching in Play store. Everytime you type in a new search it opnes a new search activity. You need to be able to handle multiple activities of the same kind.

Comment: hmm, so this way we cant handle killing multiple activities of same kind,
cz it will only kill the current activity and rest of the activities will remain same

Comment: We could possibly use a collection of WeakReferences. Maybe an ArrayList with WeakReferences with callbacks which would remove the vacated reference from the list so it doesnt grow uncontrollably.

Comment: exactly, an arraylist will work in that case, but i think for above case it will work fine. Isn't it?

Comment: I dare not say. If OP has only one instance of each activity at one time it should suffice.

Answer (score -1):

```
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit App?");
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        })

                .setNegativeButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                moveTaskToBack(true);
                                android.os.Process
                                        .killProcess(android.os.Process
                                                .myPid());
                                System.exit(0);

                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Sorry@Demo Sharma,it doesn't work

Comment: Do not use System,exit().  Many reasons not to but mainly because it screws up Androids app memory management.